# How to set backgroundGround color in Rect spark

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
<s:Group id="ellipse2" x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100">
                <s:Rect width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0"> 
                    <s:stroke> 
                        <s:LinearGradientStroke weight="1"> 
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xFF0000"/> 
                        </s:LinearGradientStroke> 
                    </s:stroke> 
                </s:Rect>
                <s:Label id="label" text="Hello World" width="100%" height="100%" textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" />
            </s:Group>
```

I've tried to set the backgroundColor from the styles, but that doesn't worked, how can I set the backgroundColor, not the gradient?

Comment: There isn't really a background color; as Rect only have a single "layer" as I understood it.  I think you want to make your fill a  SolidColor http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/SolidColor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Reboog711 stated: the Spark primitive graphics components like `Rect` do not support styles. They are intended to be light weight objects, and thus don't have all the capabilities that other Flex components do.

It sounds like you want to set the `fill` property of the `Rect`:

```
<s:Rect width="100" height="100">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#ff0000"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

The `fill` can be a `SolidColor` as above, or you can use use one of the other classes that implements the `IFill` interface: `BitmapFill`, `LinearGradient`, or `RadialGradient`.

Answer (score 0):

The "stroke" tag is used for giving the color to a "line" not for an area/region. To fill background of area/region, you should use this:

```
<s:Rect width="100" height="100">
 <s:fill>
  <s:SolidColor color="yourColorCode" />
 </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```